# How to identify a a javascript prototype method callee's name from another prototype method

Tags: javascript

Having two javascript "object classes" **MyClass1** and **MyClass2** where a method (**foo**) in MyClass1 **calls** a method (**moo**) in MyClass2, I need to identify dynamically who is calling the function prototype **moo** from **moo** itself.

When I use the popularly suggested arguments.callee.caller accessors, I cannot derive the name. Overall I need to know from the method **moo** that it was was called from MyClass1's moo method, or others.

```
function MyClass1() {
    this.myAttribute1 = 123;
}

MyClass1.prototype.foo = function () {
     var myclass2 = new MyClass2();
     myclass2.moo();
};


function MyClass2() {
    this.mySomething = 123;
}

MyClass2.prototype.moo = function () {
     console.log("arguments.callee.caller.name = " +
         arguments.callee.caller.name);
     console.log("arguments.callee.caller.toString() = " +
         arguments.callee.caller.toString());
};
```

In the above example the results of *arguments.callee.caller.name* are empty, while the caller's toString() method shows the function's body but not its owner class or name of the method.

The reason for this need is that I want to create a debug method that traces the calls from method to method. I extensively use Object classes and methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to name your function expressions. Try this:

```
function MyClass1() {
    this.myAttribute1 = 123;
}

MyClass1.prototype.foo = function foo() { // I named the function foo
     var myclass2 = new MyClass2;
     myclass2.moo();
};

function MyClass2() {
    this.mySomething = 123;
}

MyClass2.prototype.moo = function moo() { // I named the function moo
     console.log("arguments.callee.caller.name = " +
         arguments.callee.caller.name);
     console.log("arguments.callee.caller.toString() = " +
         arguments.callee.caller.toString());
};
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QhNJ6/

The problem is that you're assigning a function which has no name to `MyClass1.prototype.foo`. Hence it's `name` property is an empty string (`""`). You need to name your function expressions and not just your properties.

---

If you want to identify whether `arguments.callee.caller` is from `MyClass1` then you would need to do this:

```
var caller = arguments.callee.caller;

if (caller === MyClass1.prototype[caller.name]) {
    // caller belongs to MyClass1
} else {
    // caller doesn't belong to MyClass1
}
```

Note however that this method depends upon the `name` of the function being the same as the property name defined on `MyClass1.prototype`. If you assign a function named `bar` to `MyClass1.prototype.foo` then this method won't work.

Comment: thanks. I not even know it was possible to name the method function. so simple. BTW, do you know how to identify that the caller (foo) is from Class MyClass1 ?

Comment: @gextra Yes it is possible. I updated my answer to demonstrate how.